# Import Error while installing a package using setup.py

Tags: python

I tried to run "python setup.py install" but facing the import error i.e Import error: No module named xlrd
This module xlrd module is imported in "master_to_json" script still xlrd is placed in the install requires in the setup function.
master_to_json.py contains

```
import xlrd
..
def main():
....
....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

setup.py contains:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
from distutils.dir_util import mkpath
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

from dictionary_tools.tools.dictionary import master_to_json
from dictionary_tools.tools.dictionary  import common
setup(
    name=common.PROGRAM,
    version=common.VERSION,
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            master_to_json.__program__ + ' = dictionary_tools.tools.dictionary.master_to_json:main',
        ]
    },
install_requires=["xlrd >= 0.9.2", "xlwt >= 0.7.5"],
long_description=open('README.txt').read()
)
```

when executed as

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Comment: You import `master_to_json` which on turn imports `xlrd` before actually installing xlrd, hence it can't find it

Comment: you have to install xlrd before to import it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are trying to import `master_to_json` sooner, then is your setup() executed.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
from distutils.dir_util import mkpath
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

from dictionary_tools.tools.dictionary import master_to_json # <- here is the problem
from dictionary_tools.tools.dictionary  import common
```

Your stack trace is very likely to report this in the deeper level of call.

General advice: do not import in `setup.py` anything, what is not necessary to run `setup()`, this has to be done in the script you will run after the installation is done.

My guess is, you should simplify your setup.py (not tested) by removing any dependency on not yet installed packages.